# Apache MyFaces ERROR_HANDLING Context Parameter VS javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE

Tags: jsf-2, web.xml, myfaces

Could anyone verify that these context parameters are equivalent?

It would appear that setting javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE to 'Development' has the same effect as setting org.apache.myfaces.ERROR_HANDLING to 'true'.

I have seen plenty of examples where jacax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE and/or faces.DEVELOPMENT are explicitly set to FALSE whilst org.apache.myfaces.ERROR_HANDLING is set to TRUE.

First impressions suggest that the initial setting of FALSE is redundant and I would speculate that the use of PROJECT_STAGE is better since it is agnostic to specific implementations of the JSF Specification?

Thanks

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>
            org.apache.myfaces.ERROR_HANDLING
        </param-name>
        <param-value>
            true
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came across the answer to this in a text book today.

`javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` instruments the user of `ERROR_HANDLING` levels.

Thus they are not equivalent but the use of one brings about the action of the other.

It was introduced in JSF 2.0.

Owing to its definition in the API, it is more proper for `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` to be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.myfaces.ERROR_HANDLING

It indicates myfaces is responsible to handle errors. By specifying the value as either true or false.

where as facelets.DEVELOPMENT

Indicates that facelets are responsible to handle errors.

Both mechanisms work to handle Exceptions and provide a detailed stack trace.

The error handling mechanism provided by MyFaces kicks in before the container's default error page mechanism thus by setting its value to false we disable this ability to handle exceptions.